# Чем анализировать Netflow?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, mikrotik

Я раздаю нескольким людям интернет с помощью NAT на обычном Микротике. И в свете политического произвола в стране, боюсь, что ко мне могут прийти с обвинениями в каком-нибудь, например, плохом комментарии Вконтакте, хотя я его и не оставлял, а сделал это мой "клиент".

Поэтому вопрос номер раз: как отследить кто именно из внутренней локальной сети оставил коммент в такой-то день, в такую-то секунду много лет назад.

Первое, что мне приходит на ум - хранить записи Netflow. То есть, подняв потоки за это время я увижу какой локальный IP обращался к внешним IP ВК в это время. Поправьте, если я не прав.

Зацепившись за эту мысль, я успешно настроил Netflow IPFIX на микротике, поставил nfdump на сервачке с Ubuntu и теперь у меня полно файликов с двоичными данными. А вот для их простого анализа никак не могу подобрать инструмент. И это вопрос номер два.

Если я прав в первой части своего вопроса, то подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь анализатор или коллектор/анализатор Netflow с веб-интерфейсом под линукс для простого и понятного поиска запросов пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

С веб-интерфейсом — это уж самостоятельно через базу, а так привязать трафик ко времени можно через flow-cat/flow-nfilter/flow-print из пакета flow-tools.

Comment: Ну, может, есть какая виндовая софтина или любой другой удобный способ поанализировать, кроме как из CLI

Comment: @seventh `wireshark` пробовали?

Comment: flow-tools самое простое из консольных

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ntop.org/products/traffic-analysis/ntop/ коллектор/анализатор Netflow с веб-интерфейсом под линукс для простого и понятного поиска запросов пользователей. Но половина функций присутствует только в платной версии.